# Error 402: App packaging failed: 'Failed synchronizing resource pool'

Tags: cloud-foundry

When trying to push an app to cloudfoundry.com I get this error from vmc:

```
Error 402: App packaging failed: 'Failed synchronizing resource pool'
```

I'm not sure what to do now. The app is STOPPED, there are no logs and no files.

Comment: Couple of things:

What is your application? Is it a Java App (Spring) or Ruby? 
What version of vmc are you using? 
Does your application work on your localhost?

Comment: Sinatra/rack app. works fine locally. vmc 0.3.17
How does one troubleshoot this stuff?

Comment: We (CF.com Support) have inquired with the operations team about this issue. Did the problem occur on May 31, or was it earlier? Are you still seeing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should have been fixed in an update to CloudFoundry.com in late May. Please let us know if you see it again, or file a support ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com