# Why do I get Error 402: App packaging failed: Failed synchronizing resource pool when vmc push?

Tags: cloud-foundry

When I google for it, this is the link [Error 402: App packaging failed: 'Failed synchronizing resource pool'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826721/error-402-app-packaging-failed-failed-synchronizing-resource-pool) that shows up and it says that it has already been resolved already.

Using vmc 0.3.21, rails 3.2 app.

```
vmc push funsole
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: y
Pushing application 'funsole'...
Creating Application: OK
Creating Service [mysql-funsole]: OK
Binding Service [mysql-funsole]: OK
Creating Service [redis-funsole]: OK
Binding Service [redis-funsole]: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (27K): OK   
Error 402: App packaging failed: 'Failed synchronizing resource pool'
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried deploying it to a Micro Cloud Foundry instance?

I assume you have also deleted the application tried to redeploy it too. If the app source is available somewhere I would be more than happy to try and deploy it myself and see if I can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Well I haven't on micro one. It would be helpful if it shows the log. But vmc logs or vmc crashlogs show nothing, but blank. I've redeployed the app so the source is there. The app name is funsole under the user millisami Can you look at it what causes this log-less error?

Comment: I setup a micro cloudfoundry instance and tried it, its the same error. Then when I see the logfiles, there is one staging.log. But it contents doesn't have much information. https://gist.github.com/3933796 How to view more verbose logs?

Comment: Hi, is this still an issue? Would it be possible to get a copy of the application so we can try it on another instance?

Comment: Yup, I think but I've not tried to push either coz I couldn't get any good backtrace on the error that occured. It would be much better if VMC cloud give the informative error backtrace message on what went wrong instead of just a single vague line.

Answer (score 1):

Before the app upload to the Cloud Controller, vmc will check whether the files already in Cloud Controller resource pool, if yes, then it will rm those existing local files, and sync them at CC; if not, vmc will package all the local files to upload.

As a result, this exception was caught at some occasions:

1. The permission of the resource dir in Cloud Controller not right;
2. Using Cloud Controller cluster while the resource dir not shared;

You cloud have a check for these;